# When dragging a row in a QTableWidget, how can I find out what row index it was dragged FROM and TO?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to keep some array data synchronized with the contents of a QTableWidget.  I'd like to enable drag and drop reordering (moving items within the table, as opposed to copying), but it's not clear to me how, when the drop event is fired, I can find out what index the item was dragged FROM.  Hence, I have no way of knowing what object to move within the list I'm synchronizing with.  How can I get the original row index of the item being dragged?

Answer (score 3):

Encode the from index in QMimeData and store it in the QDrag object with setMimeData(). When the drop event occurs, extract the data from the QDropEvent with mimeData().

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Override the QTableWidget::mimeData function. Call the base class implementation, then stuff your own custom MIME type into the QMimeData, and return it.

Step 2. Override the QTableWidget::dropEvent function. If your MIME data is in the QMimeData, accept the drop and extract your data. Use the QTableWidget::indexAt to find what row/column the drop went into.

Answer (score 0):

[`QDropEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/qdropevent.html#source) has a `source()` function that will give you the widget that started the drag drop event.  Then do a `qobject_cast<QTableWidget>` on the `source`.  Once you verify the pointer, call [`QTableWidget::findItems`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/qtablewidget.html#findItems) to get the row of the item.

So something like this:

```
void dropEvent ( QDropEvent * event ) {
  if (event) {
    QTableWidget* table = qobject_cast<QTableWidget*>(event->source());
    if (table) {
      QString item = ""// Decode MIME data here.
      Qt::MatchFlag someFlag = Qt::MatchExactly; // Check documentation for match type.
      QList<QTableWidgetItem *> items = table->findItems(item, someFlag)
      // If you don't have repeats, items[0] is what you want.
      int initialRow = table->row(items[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

I tend to use model/view classes so this might be a little off, but it should work.